Change iRedAdmin roundcube url
Good day,
I am encountering an issue with iRedAdmin. Currently, accessing my webmail requires navigating to mydomain.com/mail. Furthermore, visiting the base domain mydomain.com automatically redirects to mydomain.com/mail.
I have attempted to find a solution online, but the available information primarily pertains to Apache2, whereas my server is running Nginx.
I believe that modifying the Roundcube template file and disabling the automatic redirection may resolve the issue. Could someone please provide guidance on how to change the template and prevent the automatic redirect?
Thank you in advance for your assistance.
